# In Dart, how to verify a void method that does not throw exception in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I am implementing some data verification library in Dart. The validating method has `void` return type and throws exceptions on errors. The code below shows an example.

```
import 'package:quiver/check.dart';
    
void validate(int value) {
    checkArgument(value >= 0 && value <= 100);
}
```

In unit tests, I could use following code to test the exception case for invalid input:

```
expect(() => validate(-1), throwsArgumentError);
```

However, how to verify that the method does not throw exception for a valid input?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`package:test` provides a [`returnsNormally`](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/returnsNormally-constant.html) `Matcher`.  You'd use it in the same way as the `throwsA`/etc. `Matcher`s where it matches against a zero-argument function:

```dart
expect(() => validate(-1), returnsNormally);
```

Even though allowing your function to throw an uncaught exception ultimately would result in a failed test regardless, using `returnsNormally` can result in a clearer failure message.

For completeness (no pun intended), the equivalent for an asynchronous function would be to use the [`completes`](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/expect/completes.html) matcher:

```dart
await expectLater(someAsynchronousFunction(), completes);
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just call the method.
If it does throw, then the test will fail.